# C#: Convert a UInt16 in string format into an integer(decimal)

Tags: c#

Here's the problem.

I ,for example,have a string "2500".Its converted from byte array into string.I have to convert it to decimal(int).

This is what I should get:

```
string : "2500"
byte[] : {0x25, 0x00}
UInt16 : 0x0025 //note its reversed
int    : 43     //decimal of 0x0025
```

How do I do that?

Comment: decimal of 0x0025 is 37 not 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from hex string to UInt16 is `UInt16.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)`.

You'll need to write some code to do the "reversal in two-digit blocks" though.  If you have control over the code that generates the string from the byte array, a convenient way to do this would be to build the string in reverse, e.g. by traversing the array from length - 1 *down* to 0 instead of in the normal upward direction.  Alternatively, assuming that you know it's exactly a 4 character string, `s = s.Substring(2, 2) + s.Substring(0, 2)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to explicitly specify what base you want with [Convert.ToUInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8444cfyw.aspx).

Then, you can flip it around with [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht0w88zx.aspx) (though you'll have to cast it to an int16, then cast the result back to a uint16.

Answer (score 1):

there is a special class for conversion : Convert
to convert from string to uint16 use the following method: Convert.ToUInt16

for difference on int.parse and Convert.ToInt32 is explained in [this](http://anuviswan.blogspot.com/2006/03/intparse-vs-converttoint32.html) page

and the msdn site for Convert.ToUInt16 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.touint16.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is always 4 digits long.
You can get away with one string variable but I'm using multiple ones for readability.

```
string originalValue = "2500";
string reverseValue = originalValue.Substring(2, 2) + originalValue.Substring(0, 2);
string hexValue = Convert.ToUInt16(reverseValue, 16).ToString();
int result = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 10);
```